# how to differentiate it was signed in as customer or captain/driver

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm using firebase to login to my app there are two users customer and driver .i log in as driver/captain after app restart without asking for sign in as customer or driver it moves to customer side.just because of user.getInstance()
how to differenciate how was signed in first

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_login);


        nAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuthListener= new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user =FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user!=null){
                    Intent intent= new Intent(CustomerLoginActivity.this, CustomerMapActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);



                }

            }
        };

        nEmail= findViewById(R.id.email);
        nPassword= findViewById(R.id.password);
        nLogIn= findViewById(R.id.login);
        new_user= findViewById(R.id.new_user);
        new_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               if(user_Type=="Customer") {
                    final String email = nEmail.getText().toString();
                    final String password = nPassword.getText().toString();
                    nAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this, "Sign Up Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                String user_id = nAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(user_id);
                                current_user_db.setValue(true);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else if(user_Type=="Captain"){
                    final String email =  nEmail.getText().toString();
                    final String password =  nPassword.getText().toString();
                    nAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this , "Sign Up Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                String user_id= nAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(user_id);
                                current_user_db.setValue(true);
                            }
                }
            });
                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this , "Select Any User Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
        nLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (user_Type=="Customer") {
                    final String email = nEmail.getText().toString();
                    final String password = nPassword.getText().toString();
                    nAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this, "Sign Up Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                else if(user_Type=="Captain"){


                    final String email =  nEmail.getText().toString();
                    final String password =  nPassword.getText().toString();
                    nAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this , "Sign Up Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this , "Select Any User Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

actually using that email registered as captain but it login as customer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only restarting the application, then you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference customer = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customer"); 
DatabaseReference driver = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driver");
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(user!=null){
    customer.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { 
      @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.exists() && user != null) { 
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this, CustomerActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
      } else {
         driver.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && user != null) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this, DriverActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
               finish();
             }
          }
          @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
       }
         @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
       });
```

Here, you retrieve the `FirebaseUser` then you check if the `userId` is under either the `customer` node or the `driver` node, and then you navigate to the specific activity.

For the above to work, you need to have the following database:

```
customer
   userId
      name : customer_1
driver
   userId
      name : driver_1
```